# How to print an element of RDD using foreach in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

All,

I have a RDD that can be printed using

```
ratings.take(3).foreach (x => println(x))
Rating(112,123,12.0)
Rating(123,234,12.0)
Rating(156,342,43.0)
```

How can I print the element of each RDD, something like:

```
Rating (112, 12.0)
Rating (123, 12.0)
```

I tried `ratings.take(3).foreach (x => println(x_1))` but not working...

Comment: Show us the definition of `Rating`.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working ?

Comment: `println(ratings.map(x => (x._2, x._3)).take(3).toList)`